# How to remove row of recycler view by swiping or sliding in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am using Recycler View. This is my very first time of using Recycler View. I using it together with CardView. The reason why I am using recycler view is I want to remove row by swiping left or right. But I cannot find event to do it in Recycler View. How can I set it? Is it built-in included in Recycler View?

I installed using grandle like this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'

 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
```

This is my adapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<CardData> values;

    public CardAdapter(ArrayList<CardData> valuesPram)
    {
        this.values = valuesPram;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name,email;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
            email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_email);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardData cardData = values.get(position);
        holder.email.setText(cardData.getEmail());
        holder.name.setText(cardData.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }
}
```

This is my row layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Integer> removedItems;

    private ArrayList<CardData> listItems;
    private CardAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeData();
        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView()
    {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private void initializeData()
    {
        listItems = new ArrayList<CardData>();
        CardData item1 = new CardData();
        item1.setName("Name 1");
        item1.setEmail("Email 1");
        listItems.add(item1);
        CardData item2 = new CardData();
        item2.setName("Name 2");
        item2.setEmail("Email 2");
        listItems.add(item2);
        CardData item3 = new CardData();
        item3.setName("Name 3");
        item3.setEmail("Email 3");
        listItems.add(item3);
        CardData item4 = new CardData();
        item4.setName("Name 4");
        item4.setEmail("Email 4");
        listItems.add(item4);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listItems);
    }

    private void removeItem(View v)
    {
        int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedItemPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My code is working fine. My question is how can I implement event for removing item by swiping left or right to one of the rows of recycler view?

Comment: Did you try anything for swipe to dismiss ??

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: I looked for an event. But I did not get it. @RakshitNawani

Comment: So I must use it instead? @KeyurLakhani ?

Comment: You can find many libraries if you search google, try it once and if you face any problem then question again someone will help you for sure

Comment: You should be able to achieve it with a simple gesture detector but it takes some work.

Comment: If you would have done any research you might have come across this http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html (swipe gestures from support library) There are plenty examples / tutorials on SO and Google

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use ItemTouchHelper provided by RecyclerView itself

```
//Swipe to Delete
    ItemTouchHelper swipeToDismissTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
        {

          // Do Stuff


        }

    });
    swipeToDismissTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's small piece of code named `ItemTouchHelper` developed by @iPaulPro. It works perfect and supports dragging and swiping of virtually any `RecyclerView`. All you need is to implement 3 simple interfaces + slightly rewrite callback class (in simple cases works provided callback class).

Here's a [link in github](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo)

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your project **SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener**  add the following line in your activity

```
 SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener touchListener =
                new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener(
                        recyclerObject,
                        new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {

                                    return true;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (final int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

                                   your_array.remove(position);

                                }
                                // do not call notifyItemRemoved for every item, it will cause gaps on deleting items
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        recyclerObject.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

**SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener**

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    // Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
    private int mSlop;
    private int mMinFlingVelocity;
    private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    // Fixed properties
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DismissCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

    // Transient properties
    private List<PendingDismissData> mPendingDismisses = new ArrayList<PendingDismissData>();
    private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;
    private boolean mSwiping;
    private int mSwipingSlop;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mDownPosition;
    private View mDownView;
    private boolean mPaused;

    /**
     * The callback interface used by {@link coverflow.example.bala.myrecyclerview.SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener} to inform its client
     * about a successful dismissal of one or more list item positions.
     */
    public interface DismissCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called to determine whether the given position can be dismissed.
         */
        boolean   canDismiss(int position);

        /**
         * Called when the user has indicated they she would like to dismiss one or more list item
         * positions.
         *
         * @param recyclerView               The originating {@link ListView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onDismiss(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new swipe-to-dismiss touch listener for the given list view.
     *
     * @param recyclerView  The list view whose items should be dismissable.
     * @param callbacks The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
     *                  dismiss one or more list items.
     */
    public SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener(RecyclerView recyclerView, DismissCallbacks callbacks) {
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(recyclerView.getContext());
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
        mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
        mAnimationTime = recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mCallbacks = callbacks;
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
     *
     * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an {@link AbsListView.OnScrollListener} to be added to the {@link
     * ListView} using {@link ListView#setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener)}.
     * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes through
     * to this listener. This will ensure that this {@link coverflow.example.bala.myrecyclerview.SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener} is
     * paused during list view scrolling.</p>
     *
     * @see coverflow.example.bala.myrecyclerview.SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener
     */
    public RecyclerView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
        return new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                setEnabled(newState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth = mRecyclerView.getWidth();
        }

        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (mPaused) {
                    return false;
                }

                // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

                // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int childCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                mRecyclerView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                View child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView = child;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null) {
                    mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                    mDownPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(mDownView);
                    if (mCallbacks.canDismiss(mDownPosition)) {
                        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    } else {
                        mDownView = null;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (mDownView != null && mSwiping) {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(1)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
                float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                boolean dismiss = false;
                boolean dismissRight = false;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                    dismiss = true;
                    dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
                } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                        && absVelocityY < absVelocityX && mSwiping) {
                    // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                    dismiss = (velocityX < 0) == (deltaX < 0);
                    dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }
                if (dismiss && mDownPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    // dismiss
                    final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                    final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                    ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                            .alpha(0)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    performDismiss(downView, downPosition);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(1)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math.abs(deltaX) / 2) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mSwipingSlop = (deltaX > 0 ? mSlop : -mSlop);
                    mRecyclerView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                            (motionEvent.getActionIndex()
                                    << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                    mRecyclerView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                    cancelEvent.recycle();
                }

                if (mSwiping) {
                    mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX - mSwipingSlop);
                    mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                            1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class PendingDismissData implements Comparable<PendingDismissData> {
        public int position;
        public View view;

        public PendingDismissData(int position, View view) {
            this.position = position;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PendingDismissData other) {
            // Sort by descending position
            return other.position - position;
        }
    }

    private void performDismiss(final View dismissView, final int dismissPosition) {
        // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
        // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
        // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
        final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                    // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                    // Sort by descending position
                    Collections.sort(mPendingDismisses);

                    int[] dismissPositions = new int[mPendingDismisses.size()];
                    for (int i = mPendingDismisses.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        dismissPositions[i] = mPendingDismisses.get(i).position;
                    }
                    mCallbacks.onDismiss(mRecyclerView, dismissPositions);

                    // Reset mDownPosition to avoid MotionEvent.ACTION_UP trying to start a dismiss 
                    // animation with a stale position
                    mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                    for (PendingDismissData pendingDismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                        // Reset view presentation
                        pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                        pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                        lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = originalHeight;
                        pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                    // Send a cancel event
                    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(time, time,
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0);
                    mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(cancelEvent);

                    mPendingDismisses.clear();
                }
            }
        });

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        mPendingDismisses.add(new PendingDismissData(dismissPosition, dismissView));
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this would help you

```
    val simpleCallback: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback =
        object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition //get position which is swipe
                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {    //if swipe left
                    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder =
                        AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity) //alert for confirm to delete
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?") //set message
                    builder.setPositiveButton("REMOVE",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            return@OnClickListener
                        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            return@OnClickListener
                        }).show()
                }
            }
        }
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recycler)
```